# Screensaver on Ubuntu Mate 18.04 with 3 monitors

Tags: screensaver

[image]

I have a question first let me give some details. I am using Ubuntu Mate 18.04. I have an AMD GPU R7 260X using AMD drivers and I have three 24-inch monitors. My PC is a Dell XPS 8500 with 16 GB of RAM.

Here is my question, I use screensavers on my systems just for kicks. If I remember, I had to install the Xscreensavers. When my screensaver activates it displays a random screensaver on each of my monitors even though I have selected one screensaver to use (FireworkX for the time being) Not only do I get 3 different screensavers displaying simultaneously on my monitors but when I click the mouse to see my desktop, the desktop displays for a moment and then the FireworkX screensaver turns on, so I have to click the mouse again to see my desktop.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can correct this so my chosen screensaver displays on all three screens instead of getting three random screensavers?

Answer (score 0):

#### `xscreensaver` main screen:

[image: same random server.png]

From the `Display Modes` tab set the first field `Mode` to `Same Random Savers`.

As the tool-tip states:

> When idle or locked, chose a random display
>   mode from among the checked items in the
>   list below. Run that same mode on each
>   monitor.

Comment: my screensaver selection window does not have tabs for display mode or advanced. I have to scroll up to get to  Blank Screen or Random. That is part of the issue, I have Fireworkx selected as the screensaver not Random

Comment: I had a typo it is "Display Modes" tab not "Advanced" tab. In above example "PopSquares" is selected as the screen saver not "Random". When you scroll up to select the mode "Blank Screen" or "Random" is there not another mode called "Same Random Savers"?

Comment: I added a link to a screenshot of my Screensaver Preferences window so you can see what I see when I go there.

Comment: Also I dont know of any setting to run the "same mode on each monitor"

Comment: @user884841 Could you update your question with a screenshot of your `xscreensaver` configuration screen so we can see what version you are using?

Comment: I left an imgur link earlier you can check that out and I just got this back from the terminal after trying to reinstall xscreensaver, ( I knew it would give me info on the matter) 

_____________________________________________________________xscreensaver is already the newest version (5.36-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-34 linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-34-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic

Comment: @user884841 There's the problem. I'm using version ` (5.34-2ubuntu1)`. You would need to downgrade to get same version as myself.

Comment: SO I am not really sure how this worked out but I typed in the terminal apt-get remove xscreensaver, that removed a bunch of packages , maybe a dozen or so but it did not remove the entire xscreensaver. I rebooted my computer and somehow the xscreensaver is working as it should now only displaying one screensaver across all 3 monitors